# Set Windows Explorer to default to my user folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I can change the target property for explorer (Windows Explorer, not IE) to this:

%windir%\explorer.exe /n,/e,c:\Users\Admin

But I don't want to open there.  Windows seems to create something similar to a shortcut to my user folder and displays it in the desktop folder.  I want this to be the default location when explorer opens but I can't see any environment variables to use in the command line in the target.  How can I achieve this?
[image]

Seriously? Nobody can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by trial and error.
The blurred-out name of folder with the special symbol is your user name.  For example if your user name is user1 then the folder will be named that.  It can be accessed by the alias %user1%.

To make that the start folder use this target in the Shortcut tab of Windows Explorer Properties:

`%windir%\explorer.exe /n,/e,/select,%user1%`

[image]

[image]

and you will get the desired result...

[image]

As pointed out by @nakinlaulu 
`%windir%\explorer.exe /n,/e,/select,%username%` is a better solution which also gives the result I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

`%userprofile%` - environment variable that contains the path to the current user's folder

and

`{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}` - guid of user folder

should work as well

eg:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe %userprofile%

%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}
```

Comment: Thanks, _almost_ what I was looking for. Your method opens with Desktop selected in the folder panel and the one I want in the main panel. I then have to double click to select the user folder to get to where I want to be on open.  The method I eventually stumbled upon does exactly what I want and eliminates one step.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand you. if you want to open desktop folder you can append `\desktop` after the variable name, and the command you provided in the answer didn't work on my machine with `windows 10` os

Comment: [Your way](https://app.box.com/s/l0bb0cgmbdtl2gxyqbmz). [My way](https://app.box.com/s/td3vgjvib7k0h8wnif1o) Did you substitute your user name for user1?

Comment: yes, i did the substitution now, but it still doesn't open the folder, instead opens 'this pc'. ps: you could use `%username%` environment variable instead of undefined `%user1%` in the code :-)

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea why.  I'm using Windows 7.  Yes! '%username% is the best solution... also gives me exactly what I want but is generic.